# Azure Pipelines. Artifact trigger filter by name

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a pipeline which is publishing two artifacts with different names.

```
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\WPF'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
    artifact: 'WPF'
```

Then I have another pipeline which is triggered by the first pipeline.
I want to know if it's possible to do not trigger `stage1` or `stage2` when no artifact with matching name is published. The idea is not trigger pipeline in all situations, only with mathing artifact name is published.

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: 'resName' 
    source: '\Folder\PipelineName' 
    trigger: true 

stages:
  - stage: stage1

  steps:
  - checkout: none
    clean: true

  - download: resName
    artifact: WPF

- stage: stage1

  steps:
  - checkout: none
    clean: true

  - download: resName
    artifact: Xamarin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know if it's possible to do not trigger stage1 or stage2 when no artifact with matching name is published.

There is no Predefined variable can show the artifacts name of the Pipeline resource.

To meet your requirement, you need to use the Rest API: [Artifacts - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/list?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1) to Get the Artifacts list of the Pipeline Run and then set the artifacts name as variable to pass the next stages to check if it contains the artifacts name.

Here is an example:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: 'resName' 
    source: '\Folder\PipelineName' 
    trigger: true 

stages:
- stage: stagename
  jobs:
  - job: jobname
    steps:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        name:  taskname
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          
          script: |
            $token = "$(PAT)"
            
            $url="https://dev.azure.com/{orgname}/{projectname}/_apis/build/builds/$(resources.pipeline.resName.runID)/artifacts?api-version=4.1"
            
            $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
            
            $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get  -ContentType application/json
            
            $Artifactslist= ""
            
            
            foreach($Artifacts in $response.value)
            {
               $Artifactslist = "$($Artifactslist) $($Artifacts.name)"
            
            }
            
            echo $Artifactslist
            
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Artifactslist;isOutput=true]$Artifactslist"
      

- stage: stage1
  condition: contains(stageDependencies.stagename.outputs['jobname.taskname.Artifactslist'], 'WPF')
  jobs:
    - job: 
      steps:
      xxxx

- stage: stage2
  condition: contains(stageDependencies.stagename.outputs['jobname.taskname.Artifactslist'], 'Xamarin')
  jobs:
    - job: 
      steps:
      xxxx
```

**Result:**

When the Artifacts contains two artifacts, it will run all stages:

[image]

When the artifacts contains one of the artifacts, it will run the stage based on the artifacts name.

[image]

For more detailed info, you can refer to the [Cross-stage variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-output-variables-from-tasks)

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. It worked for me. It adds more steps and I think it could be a good idea to integrate it in the task without scripts but it works.